# Using Alexa as speaker over LAN

Tags: networking, alexa, wifi, audio, lan

I would like to use my Alexa as a speaker for my (windows)PC. My PC doesn't have Bluetooth and Alexa is not directly connected to my PC. Since the Alexa is connected to the same router (via WiFi) as my PC(via Ethernet), I was wondering if I could play audio over the WiFi.

What I've tried:

1. The Alexa website, alexa.amazon.com
2. try to view the speaker (Alexa) within my network settings

What I've checked through: [How can I stream audio from my phone over WiFi to a speaker or receiver?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29566/how-can-i-stream-audio-from-my-phone-over-wifi-to-a-speaker-or-receiver)

Comment: Have you checked the cost of a bluetooth USB adapter for the PC ? You may find it surprisingly affordable.

Comment: yes I have checked out some bluetooth adapters. I was wondering if it would be possible without buying anything first

Comment: Did you have any luck on this?